# Why does Sasuke have only one Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

In the latest chapters of the Naruto manga (673 and 674), why does Sasuke possess only one Rinnegan and not both?

Comment: I don't watch Naruto, so I don't know if the edit I made to the title is a spoiler. If it is, please feel free to change it to something else.

Comment: It's as much of a spoiler as it was. Either way, it is what it is.

Comment: Please do not close my question again Mr. @JNat. (˘‿˘ʃƪ)

Comment: @V-Moy I won't be closing this one, no :P This is a perfectly acceptable question here. It's spoiler-y by nature, so there's not much we can do about it.

Comment: This is an acceptable question but the answers are merely speculations/theories. The manga did not reveal when or how sasuke obtained the rinnegan. Nevertheless, still a good question.

Comment: probably because he is left dominate or that he only gets half the power of the hermit of six paths so that means one eye

Comment: Would it have been wrong to make this question more generic, e.g., "Why does this character have only one rinnegan?" or "Why does character x* have only one rinnegan?" to improve spoiler security? The x* could signal this is the most spoilery part.

Comment: Kishimoto loves Sasuke and giving him an already known power-up would make him less unique. It's a similar point as to why Sasuke has like 20 costume changes whereas Naruto only has one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters: Sasuke's Rinnegan is **not** the same as Kaguya's/Madara's Rinne Sharingan (not to be confused with Madara's Rinnegan, I'm talking about the one in the middle of the forehead of both of them).

- Sasuke's Rinnegan has 6 tomoe, Rinne Sharingan has (at least) 9.
- Sasuke's Rinnegan is blue, Rinne Sharingan is red.

The reason Sasuke only has the Rinnegan in one eye was not mentioned or explained in either the series or the data book. So we can only speculate.

In no particular order, here are my speculations:

- Hagoromo only gave Sasuke enough chakra to awaken the Rinnegan in one eye.
- That's the best Sasuke can do without fusing Asura's chakra.
- It's the cool factor.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that he chose not to use the other one. With the Rinnegan not able to use Sharingan's abilities, it's probably better to use both at the same time. Madara was seen switching back and forth between the Rinnegan and Sharingan, so it should be something that Sasuke can do as well.

Comment: The switching you mentioned happened only in Anime. Not in manga.

Comment: Madara was able to use all of the Sharingan's abilities with the rinnegan active. So that point is almost surely false.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the other eye is only for Sharingan, or he can't have two Rinnegans because it might replace his Sharingan permanently. However, one thing is for sure: he might use Sharingan and Rinnegan at the same time in the future.

Comment: I guess it's only your speculation. Try to support your answer by providing some facts or cite some sources. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Sasuke's Rinnegan is exactly the same Rinnegan of Kaguya's 3rd eye and Madara's 3rd eye. Since, Madara's 3rd eye and Kaguya's 3rd eye are one and the same, this means that there is only one such eye.

This Rinnegan with Sharingan tomoe has always been a one eye case from the beginning. It is very different from Madara's Rinnegan, which is same as Hagoromo's pair of eyes.

Comment: Can you give a source or link for your 'claim' about "*Sasuke's rinnegan is exact same rinnegan of Kaguya's 3rd eye and Madara's 3rd eye it awoke*"? Thanks