# Does Sasuke have only one Rinnegan eye because he only got half of Hagoromo's chakra?

Tags: naruto

To awaken the Rinnegan, you need Hagoromo's chakra, the first user of Rinnegan.

Madara had acquired Asura's chakra, which let him awaken Hagoromo's chakra. Even though the chakra eventually gets depleted, his Rinnegan still functions while it feeds on Madara's chakra. In this case now the six path chakra is not in half, it was full.

Sasuke only received half of Hagoromo's chakra. His Rinnegan also has tomoe, and consumes chakra when it's active, even without been used.  That is something which doesn't happen with the normal Rinnegan.  This suggests that Sasuke still retains the Sharingan in his left eye, yet has access to the normal powers of the Rinnegan, despite that eye not being "fully" evolved.

Because Sasuke only got half of Hagoromo's chakra, is this the reason that his Rinnegan is imperfect and in only one of his eyes?

Comment: i have edited to be a question about the series rather than a fan theory keeping to the suggestions made [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4014/1587). i belive i have still retained the purpose of the theory abotu if the reason why Sasuke has only one Rinnegan is because it's incomplete from him only getting half of Hagoromo's chakra

Comment: For context into the edit, [please refer to this Meta discussion.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4014/102)

Comment: Prob because you need more chakra to awaken two rinnegan. Hagoromo only gave him half his cahkra, so lo and behold, one reinnegan!

Comment: Related: [Why does Sasuke have only one Rinnegan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8848/why-does-sasuke-have-only-one-rinnegan?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why Sasuke only has one Rinnegan has never been mentioned or explained in the Anime or Manga. This obviously hasn't stopped speculation from surrounding it though.

My speculations for why Sasuke only has one Rinnegan would be:

- Like you said, Sasuke only received half of Hagoromo's Chakra and therefore only manifested one Rinnegan
- Sasuke's Six Tomoe Rinnegan is special and does not come in pairs like the common Rinnegan
- The Sharingan is such an iconic part of Sasuke's appearance that Kishimoto did not want to completely replace it.

On a side note, Sasuke's Rinnegan is not considered imperfect. Although, it does retain the abilities of his Sharingan, this has been observed in other Sharingan/Rinnegan users, such as Hagoromo and Madara. It also doesn't feed on his chakra if he's not using it, but he does have to close his Rinnegan if he overuses it.

I hope I answered your question and please correct me if I'm wrong on any points.

Comment: i agree with you

Answer (score 0):

That is partly the case. You see, Hagoromo is the son of Kaguya, the fruit of chakra. So, he is the descendant of the creator of chakra. He creates the yin release and yang release. Naruto gets the yin half, while Sasuke gets the yang half. Anybody with the yang half can get the special type of Rinnegan, called the Magatama Rinnegan (I think).

Comment: am not satisfised with that answer