# Shouldn't Naruto be able to regain Kurama's chakra, and Sasuke, his Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto, boruto

The following contains spoilers about recent Boruto chapters. Markdowns will still be added.

> As of Chapter 53, Boruto was controlled by Momoshiki via [Kāma](https://boruto.fandom.com/wiki/Karma#:%7E:text=Karma%20(%E6%A5%94%2C%20K%C4%81ma)%20is,%C5%8Ctsutsuki%22%20for%20the%20clan%20member.), then proceeds to stab Sasuke's left eye which possesses a Rinnegan in order to block him of Amenotejikara, his Space-Time ability. And also, of Chapter 55 of the Boruto manga, Kurama dies after the use of "Baryon Mode" which combined Naruto and Kurama's chakra.

I will be breaking this question down as to why I feel Naruto and Sasuke should be able regain these powers, starting with Naruto.

According to the wiki:

> The Ten-Tailed Beast (十尾, Jūbi) is the original, primordial demon of the Naruto universe. All nine of the tailed beasts are but portions of chakra divided from the Ten-Tails.

Considering the Ten Tailed Beast (Juubi) is the combination of all nine Biju's (Tailed Beast) Chakra, this should mean logically that Kurama's chakra is the mixture of all Tailed Beasts from one to eight tails. Considering this, the Bijuu should be able to reform Kurama's chakra by mixing theirs, and give it to Naruto so he can get some Nine-Tails chakra back. Should or shouldn't this work?

Now, to the second part of the question.

According to a [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/80org4/how_did_sasuke_get_the_rinnegan/) page I found:

> Sasuke already possessed the chakra of Indra when he receives half of Hagoromo's chakra, so he is able to awaken the Rinnegan! ... Sasuke literally got Chakra from the sage of six paths thus also getting a rinnegan because you could say that he has both indra and ashura's Chakra because he has sage of six paths Chakra.

Sasuke awakened a Rinnegan because Hagoromo's Six Paths chakra synced with his left eye's EMS, thus forming a Tomoe-Rinnegan. Considering Sasuke still possesses Six Paths Chakra (as to why his Chidori is sometimes purple, he adds Six Paths Chakra to it)

> Shouldn't he be able to awaken a new Rinnegan in his left eye **if he replaces it**, due to the Six Paths Chakra once again syncing with his left EMS?

Answer (score 2):

Well based on the above facts I could say maybe since most of the time the sharingan users are bound to control a power based on emotions. On his case, true he has the power of Six paths Chakra but when he uses the rinnegan you can witness that he needs to charge it to it's full capacity which is why you could see the **Tomoe** those dots represents the charged state. So I guess he can bring out the rinnegan in his left eye but will he be able to use it for that I would say it might take time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about **Kurama** I'll say about the past and present of it

**Nine Tails**

**Past:**

1. Controlled by one of the badass ninja named "Uchiha Madara".
2. Forcefully placed into Naruto by his parents cause they don't want the village to be destroyed and sacrificed him.
3. When Naruto used the power it wasn't compatible with his puny body so it tends to go berserk many a times. (You might have watched the anime so I'm just saying stay with me here)
4. Kumara is a prided beast so it just accepted to work along with him rather than get controlled.

**Present:**

1. He still is prideful and loves the journey with Naruto more like nakama (Friends).

So to answer your question, kurama still has it's pride as the strongest one among every others. So, it would think if by using those combined powers only they could survive it would rather try and die than get help.

So to conclude on this it is it's pride that kills it. And well you know the tailed beasts can reincarnate after they die.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the question, I will need to discuss some of the flaws in your assumptions. Firstly, the sum of the first eighth tailed beasts chakra does not equate to the Kurama (nine tails) chakra. Although kurama is the most powerful of them all, the tailed beast power equivalency is not exactly like a russian doll stack up. All of the [tailed beasts](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Tailed_Beast) are unique sentient masses of chakra that were gotten from splitting up the ten tails, hence, combining their chakra together can only if ever, reproduce the original ([ten tails](https://narutobijuu.fandom.com/wiki/Juubi)).

Secondly, although we were never explicitly told why sasuke was only able to awaken one Rinnegan, I agree with Madara's Ghosts [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8848/why-does-sasuke-have-only-one-rinnegan) that this was more likely as a result of insufficient chakra  from Hagoromo to completely awaken a complete set.

Thirdly, whether Sasuke still possesses SO6P's chakra is unknown. However, we can kinda assume that neither he nor Naruto still do. I firmly believe that they both exhausted that Chakra during their final battle, cause when you think about it, both of them have not displayed even close to the level of strength that they both used during thier final battle (not even against Isshiki who wrecked them big time. why would they choose not to use SO6P's chakra in such a life-death situation?? hint: cause they don't have it).

Now to answer the question, taking a piece of all the tailed beasts would not recreate the Kyuubi. However, it is possible for someone with a god-like understanding of ying-yang release to actually use the [creation of all things technique](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Creation_of_All_Things_Technique) to split up a ten tailed Juubi into a new set of tailed beasts. But then again, no such individual capable of such a feat currently exists.

With regards to Sasuke's Rinnegan, it's fair to say its gone forever. Unless maybe there are some spare Rinnegans chilling in some "filler-fanservice excuse of a lab".